# Why does ASP.NET MVC4 set up a themes directory by default?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

When you create a new ASP.NET web application, a theme called "base" is automatically set up with jQuery CSS and images in it.  Is this not overkill for the large majority of web applications, which will never need to really use themes?  Is it a good idea to just move all this stuff into the root Content directory, delete the theme directory, and never use themes if you have no intention of theming your site?

I don't mean that jQuery shouldn't be included by default, that's not my point.  I mean, should it be in a "base" theme?  Themes are about being able to reskin the site, and I don't think many sites are going to want to do that.

And then, what is `Site.css` about?  That is outside of the themes dir, yet as far as I can see contains style info that one might actually want to change on a per-theme basis (like form stylings).

Comment: Do whatever you want.  It's your site.  If you don't like the theme, get rid of it.  You have the power!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try using the `Empty` template?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> a theme is automatically set up with jQuery CSS and images in it. Is this not overkill for the large majority of web applications, which will never need to really use themes?

No, this helps the majority of people to start working faster. Getting the logic done first without having to create a layout just to visualize whats going on. Not to mention that the new modern theme actually looks nice enough to be used in production if you want to. Here are a few sites that I found from a quick Google that seem to be deployed with the default template.

- [Make Differences](http://makedifferences.org/)
- [VACS Applications](http://vacs.med.yale.edu/)
- [Build A Project](http://user1323.netfx45lab.discountasp.net/Home/Home)
- [Les Taxis de Villefranche sur Mer](http://www.taxisvillefranchesurmer.com/)
- [3indians.com](http://3indians.com/)

The majority of users need the jQuery, even if only for the unobtrusive validation.

The new templates includes a lot of necessary features, for example [cell phone support and mobile projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs11trainingcourse_aspnetmvc4_topic2.aspx). Take a look at [Enhancements to Default Project Templates](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253808), for examples of what some of the new default features are and why they were included.

As for the jQuery ui, other than just the files on the server, there isn't any overhead with having it there. It's not being sent to the client unless you need it.

If you don't need any of this, you can remove it or as @Gromer pointed out you can create an empty project or even a basic project.

**Addendum**

The theme is just the default theme that the jQuery UI comes with. You can easily change it or create a custom one on the jQuery site. But the theme is there because jQuery UI won't work without it, and the UI is there to allow developers to quickly get to work with the UI.

It's similar to when you create a new controller you can have it automatically create the basic `Index`, `Details`, `Create`, `Edit` and `Delete` actions. This is just a convenience and you if you don't need it you can create an empty controller. Just like if you don't want the UI, you can create a basic or empty project.

It's just a feature of the Internet Application, most people find it helpful, and you are given the option to use it or not. If it was the other way round, people would be complaining that it wasn't included. And someone would create a template to add it just like with MVC 3, it didn't have OAuth by default and it was a hassle for people to set it up so someone created a default MVC 3 project that has OAuth by default. Now MVC 4 has OAuth support by default.

Comment: I think you're slightly missing the point of my question.  I understand why jQuery etc. is included by default, fair enough.  My question is why it needs to be set up as a theme.  I mean how many people are really going to want to reskin their site using themes?  They're going to just use one theme.

Comment: Sorry, I still think you're missing the point.  You're confusing jQuery UI themes and ASP.NET themes.  You can setup a jQuery UI theme (basically images and CSS) in a content directory without using ASP.NET themes.  ASP.NET themes are only needed if you intend to skin your site in several ways.  The vast majority of sites are not going to need or want that functionality, and as far as I can see, the `themes/base` directory just confuses where you should put styling information, especially when `Site.css` is *outside* that directory.